# Mail function is not working

Tags: email, wp-mail, contact

My mail function is not working. When I submit form it says mail sent. But not receiving. I tried echo if the mail sent. It is also working. What is the issue here? Anything with mail function ?

```
<?php
$name    = $_POST[ 'cuf_sender' . $n ];
$email   = $_POST[ 'cuf_email' . $n ];
$subject = $this->o['subpre'] . ' ' . $_POST[ 'cuf_subject' . $n ];
$msg     = $_POST[ 'cuf_msg' . $n ];

$extra = '';
foreach ( $_POST as $k => $f ) {
    if ( strpos( $k, 'cuf_field_' ) !== false ) {
        $extra .= $this->o[ substr( $k, 4, 7 ) ] . ": $f\r\n";
    }
}

$headers =
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_settings( 'blog_charset' ) . "\"\r\n";
if ( ! empty( $from ) ) {
    $headers .= "From: " . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . " - $name <$from>\r\n";
} else if ( ! empty( $email ) ) {
    $headers .= "From: " . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . " - $name <$email>\r\n";
}

$fullmsg =
    "Name: $name\r\n" .
    "Email: $email\r\n" .
    $extra . "\r\n" .
    'Subject: ' . $_POST[ 'cuf_subject' . $n ] . "\r\n\r\n" .
    wordwrap( $msg, 76, "\r\n" ) . "\r\n\r\n" .
    'Referer: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\r\n" .
    'Browser: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\r\n";

if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $fullmsg, $headers, $email ) ) {
    echo $to;
    exit();
```

Comment: Even if the mail gets send from the system, there is no guarantee that the mail will get delivered !! Check with your SMTP. May be you can use some SMTP Configure plugin and try with different SMTPs.

Comment: Please suggest one plugin

Comment: [WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/), 
[WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)
Try configuring with gmail server as the SMTP. :)

Comment: @SpamBox What is $to value?

Comment: $to is defined already. I din't include that in question

Comment: Can the WordPress core send email-- for example, the registration emails?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `$email` where there should be attachments. Look at [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) arguments.

Also you have not defined `$to` variable which in your case i assume should be `$email`.

Try this,

```
$name   = $_POST['cuf_sender'.$n];
    $email  = $_POST['cuf_email'.$n];
    $subject= $this->o['subpre'].' '.$_POST['cuf_subject'.$n];
    $msg    = $_POST['cuf_msg'.$n];

    $extra = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $f )
        if ( strpos( $k, 'cuf_field_') !== false )
            $extra .= $this->o[substr($k, 4, 7)].": $f\r\n";


    $headers =
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
    "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"".get_settings('blog_charset')."\"\r\n";
    if ( !empty($from) )
        $headers .= "From: ".get_bloginfo('name')." - $name <$from>\r\n";
    else if ( !empty($email) )
        $headers .= "From: ".get_bloginfo('name')." - $name <$email>\r\n";

    $fullmsg =
    "Name: $name\r\n".
    "Email: $email\r\n".
    $extra."\r\n".
    'Subject: '.$_POST['cuf_subject'.$n]."\r\n\r\n".
    wordwrap($msg, 76, "\r\n")."\r\n\r\n".
    'Referer: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\r\n".
    'Browser: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";

    if ( wp_mail( $email, $subject, $fullmsg, $headers) )
    {
        echo $to;
    exit();
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other suggestions, make sure that the 'from' email address is an email address that belongs to the domain of your site, and that it exists.

Some hosts will not send mail from the example.com domain when the 'from' address is 'someone@notmydomain.com'. They will sense that as a 'mail relay', which is what spammers will try, so will block the mail.

Note that the return value of the mail() function is just a flag that shows that the message was successfully/unsuccessfully sent to the mail server. It is not an indication that the mail was actually sent.

Comment: Downvote? Why? The info is correct and accurate. Perhaps someone got coal in their stocking...